# How to preserve an array or string in x86

Tags: arrays, assembly, memory, x86, x86-16

I'm programming the game "15 puzzle game" in x86 using tasm asm/dosbox. I want to "save" or "preserve" my array called 'a' that is being declared in my data segment, so that after I swap the bytes around using upArrow, downArrow, etc... and then I press 'n' for new game, I can set my array 'a' back to it's original state as it was declared in my data segment. Here is my code:

```
.MODEL TINY
.386

.DATA
PROMPT DB "Enter q to quit, arrow keys to move, n to restart (new game) HAPPY HOLIDAYS!! :)$"

;this is board preset A
a       DB 201,205,205,205,205,203,205,205,205,205,203,205,205,205,205,203,205,205,205,205,203,205,205,205,205,203,205,205,205,205,187,
    DB 186,255,48,50,255,186,255,48,49,255,186,255,48,51,255,186,255,48,52,255,186,255,48,53,255,186,255,48,54,255,186,
    DB 204,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,185,
    DB 186,255,48,55,255,186,255,48,56,255,186,255,48,57,255,186,255,49,48,255,186,255,49,49,255,186,255,49,50,255,186,
    DB 204,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,185, 
    DB 186,255,49,51,255,186,255,49,52,255,186,255,49,53,255,186,255,49,54,255,186,255,49,55,255,186,255,255,255,255,186,
    DB 204,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,206,205,205,205,205,185, 
    DB 186,255,49,56,255,186,255,49,57,255,186,255,50,48,255,186,255,50,49,255,186,255,50,50,255,186,255,50,51,255,186,
    DB 200,205,205,205,205,202,205,205,205,205,202,205,205,205,205,202,205,205,205,205,202,205,205,205,205,202,205,205,205,205,188,"$"


col DB 0
row DB 0
board DB 0

.CODE
org 100h
MAIN PROC

;initialize display step 0
MOV AH, 00h
MOV AL, 03h
INT 10h

MOV AX, 0B800h
MOV ES, AX
XOR di,di


;initialize configuration and dislay prompt step 1
newGame:
call initConfig

;display board step 2


;wait for key step 3
game:
;print board
call printBoard1

;get cursor x y
call SetCursor

MOV AH, 0
INT 16H

MOV BL, AL

;up arrow
CMP AH, 48h
jz upArrow

;down arrow
CMP AH, 50h
jz downArrow

;right arrow
CMP AH, 4dh
jz rightArrow

;left arrow
CMP AH, 4bh
jz leftArrow

;lowercase q
CMP AL, 71h
jz EXIT

;uppercase q
CMP AL, 51h
jz EXIT

;lowercase n
CMP AL, 6eh
jz newGame

;uppercase n
CMP AL, 4eh
jz newGame

jmp game

MAIN ENDP

EXIT:
MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS
INT 21H

SetCursor:
mov dl, col
mov dh, row
mov bh, 0
mov ah, 02h
int 10h
ret

getStrlen:
lodsb
cmp al, 24h
je strlen_end
inc bx
jmp getStrlen
strlen_end:
ret

loadAndDisplayStr:
lodsb
stosw
dec cx
jne loadAndDisplayStr
ret

printBoard1:
MOV board, 1
xor dx,dx
xor ax,ax
mov cx, 9
myloop1:
push cx
lea si, a
add si, dx
mov cx, 31
mov di, ax
push ax
mov ah, 4
call loadAndDisplayStr
pop ax
add ax, 160
add dx, 32
pop cx
dec cx
jnz myloop1
ret

upArrow:
xor si, si
xor di, di
lea bx, a
mov ax, 32
sub row, 2
mul row
add al, col
mov di, ax
mov ax, 32
add row, 2
mul row
add al, col
mov si, ax
mov dx, [bx+si]
xchg dx, [bx+di]
xchg [bx+si], dx
sub row, 2
jmp game

downArrow:
xor si, si
xor di, di
lea bx, a
mov ax, 32
add row, 2
mul row
add al, col
mov di, ax
mov ax, 32
sub row, 2
mul row
add al, col
mov si, ax
mov dx, [bx+si]
xchg dx, [bx+di]
xchg [bx+si], dx
add row, 2
jmp game

leftArrow:
xor si, si
xor di, di
lea bx, a
mov ax, 32
sub col, 5
mul row
add al, col
mov di, ax
mov ax, 32
add col, 5
mul row
add al, col
mov si, ax
mov dx, [bx+si]
xchg dx, [bx+di]
xchg [bx+si], dx
sub col, 5
jmp game

rightArrow:
xor si, si
xor di, di
lea bx, a
mov ax, 32
add col, 5
mul row
add al, col
mov di, ax
mov ax, 32
sub col, 5
mul row
add al, col
mov si, ax
mov dx, [bx+si]
xchg dx, [bx+di]
xchg [bx+si], dx
add col, 5
jmp game

initConfig:
;put the cursor at 00
mov col, 27
mov row, 5

;gets strlen of prompt and stores it in BX
lea si, PROMPT
xor bx, bx
call getStrlen

;display prompt
lea si, PROMPT
mov cx, bx
mov ah, 2
mov di, 5a0h
call loadAndDisplayStr
ret

END MAIN
```

The way I see it is there are 2 ways of doing this. One way would be to create an empty array, and every time the user makes a move (up/down/left/right) I can push this to a stack, and then when the user hits 'n' for new game, I just pop through that stack and reverse all the moves.

Another alternative would be to create 2 identical boards (arrays/string) 'a' and 'b', and then the user would manipulate board 'a' till they decide to hit 'n' for a new game, and then I would some how set 'a' = 'b'

Comment: Make a copy of it, exactly like you would an array in C.  It's not something you can do with one instruction (except for `rep movsb`)

Comment: @PeterCordes when you say copy, do you mean that in my data segment I should literally copy and paste my array 'a' and call it 'b'. And once that is done and the user makes changes to 'a' then hit's new game, go through the bytes of 'a' and xchg with bytes of 'b'

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic way, you just have to copy the array like you would in C.
**I'd suggest having one master copy of the data that you keep clean / untouched, never ever writing into it.**

Allocate uninitialized space for the working game state somewhere, e.g. on the stack or in the BSS<sup>1</sup>.

At the start of every game (including the first one), copy the preset whole array to the scratch space for the current game.  (e.g. with `rep movsb` or `rep movsw` after setting CX, SI, and DI.  ES and DS segment regs are already equal segment because of .model tiny.  i.e. implement a memcpy however you like.)

So you don't need to write the initializer data twice or anything like that, and only one copy of it needs to be in the file.

And no you don't need any exchanging, just a block copy.  Get the assembler to calculate the size of the whole thing by putting a label at the end, or put `datasize = $ - a` right after the end of `a` to get the size in bytes.

---

**Footnote 1**:  See @MichaelPetch's comment for details on how to declare a label in the `.data?` segment so you can use normal label/symbol syntax.  Like `gamestate datasize dup(?)`, where `datasize` is an `=` or `equ` constant you got the assembler to calculate earlier from the size of the preset.

I think `.data?` is just space past the end of where DOS loads your `.com` file, and you can use space from there out to near the end of a 64k segment where the program-loader put your stack.  (Unlike the .bss under a modern OS is *not* zeroed to start with.  That's fine for this, you want to write the space you use before you read/modify it anyway.)

---

@DavidWohlferd also suggests you could re-read part of the executable from disk, with DOS file open/read system calls.  That could be the start of a save-game mechanism.  In its simplest form, if the first `n` bytes of your program are all read-only (code and constant data) apart from this game-state array, you could read the first `n` bytes of the raw `.com` file into memory at `ds:100h` (or cs or es, it's all the same in a tiny memory model).  Overwriting instructions with themselves (like a `jmp rel16` over the data) is fine.

Comment: Given the uncomplicated nature of .COM files, I wonder how hard it would be to just re-read the data from the image.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Certainly possible, but slower and thus unlikely to be worth it for this small an array.  Interesting idea, though.  e.g. put it at a start point of 3 or 4 bytes into the file (following a `jmp` instruction, and read right back into `ds:100h` over the copy that the program loader made.  It's even fine if you have to round up the read size if following stuff is read-only and thus hasn't changed since program startup.  (Put your RW data at the end of the file.)  Although I assume DOS read functions could do arbitrary byte sizes, not 512B sector blocks like maybe BIOS raw disk.

Comment: Not sure how much of a performance hit this would be.  I have no idea what caching DOS did, but given that DOSBOX runs under some other OS, "reading from disk" here probably does no such thing.  In any case, it's likely to be in the "imperceptible" range.  Memory probably isn't a constraint here, so making a copy as you suggest seems an easier solution.  Still, nice to consider multiple options.  My way could form the basis to "save" games.  Then "new" and "load" could be very similar.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: I think I've read that DOS did literally zero disk caching.  Given that it has no way to regain control and free up space used for cache once a program is running, that makes sense.  (Although probably some TSRs could hook in and add some disk caching.)  And yes of course if you run in an emulator, the filesystem or disk reads will be cached by the host OS.  But it might not be imperceptible on a real DOS machine with a real floppy disk, especially if the user ejected the floppy after loading the game.  You'd hear the disc, and pathname lookup would take some seeks before data.

Comment: Wasn't there a "buffers" command in config.sys?  Seems like that's what this was for.  And wasn't there a smartdrv?  Wow, that was a long time ago.  IAC, while actual DOS may have been slow reading from a floppy, it seems unlikely OP has that kind of hw.  And he explicitly references "dosbox" which renders it moot.  Even it he was on a floppy, the OS would still cache it.  As I said, your way is probably easier to write if "new" is the only feature you plan to add.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Oh IDK, I never had DOS on my own computer. A friend had a PC when I was growing up.  I went from Atari ST to Debian GNU/Linux on my first PC (PMMX). If you're only running in an emulator, it makes no sense to be stingy about just using more RAM.  And if you only care about running on modern hardware, why would you write 16-bit DOS code in the first place?  So the only thing that makes any sense to me is to write code that would be good on real hardware, possibly even retro hardware.  Obviously you use an emulator for testing, but that's not the point.

Comment: Actually I did have a few DOS games later on another PC that normally ran Windows, but it was never my main OS.  So I think `buffers` sounds familiar.  And yeah, https://web.csulb.edu/~murdock/buffers.html confirms it was for disk readahead, but in real DOS it wasn't a full-fledged cache.  You mention smartdrv; that would be one of the TSRs I mentioned, but yeah it may have been widespread to enable some kind of drive caching on later hardware with more RAM vs. the size of a floppy.

Comment: With the simplified models you can declare a `.data?` segment for uninitialized _near_ data. If you defined `datasize` as you suggested with `datasize EQU $-a` (I use `EQU` so `datasize` can't be redefined later)  then, within the `.data?` segment you could do something like `copya datasize dup(?)` to allocate the space. With MASM/TASM/JWASM `.data?` produces a _BSS segment into the object. Not related to this situation, I should note that the DOS loader doesn't zero out BSS or STACK memory, that has to be done by the program.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: If you'd like, feel free to edit an example of the declaration into my answer.  And BTW, yeah I was guessing DOS wouldn't zero a BSS because there's no metadata to tell it how much space you want to use past the end of the file, and it's not going to zero all the way to where it puts the stack.  But thanks for confirming, will edit my answer to say so instead of just being compatible with that.